# Unable to deploy sample webservice in jBOSS 5.1

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, jboss5.x

Am new to webservice. With the help of few online tutorials, I built up an local project, a webservice. Below is the class

```
package com.arun;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
public class HelloClass {

    @WebMethod()
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hi " + name + ". Welcome to webservice.";
    }

}
```

Am creating a WAR of this and putting it in jBOSS-5.1. This is how i create WAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="reads" default="build_app_war" basedir=".">

    <property file="build.properties"/>



    <target name="init" depends="clean">
        <!-- Create the time stamp -->
        <tstamp/>
        <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
        <echo message=" ***** Creating build directory ***** "/>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <echo message=" ***** Build directory created***** "/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source " >
        <echo message=" ***** Compiling source files ***** "/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="true"/>

        <echo message=" ***** Compilation completed ***** "/>
    </target>

    <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
        <!-- Create the distribution directory -->

        <echo message=" ***** Generating jar file ***** "/>
        <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
        <jar jarfile="${dist.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/webserviceTest.jar" basedir="${build.dir}"/>

        <echo message=" ***** Jar file created ***** "/>


    </target>

    <target name="build_app_war" description="Builds the READS war file" depends="dist">
        <echo message=" **** Building webserviceTest War file... "/>

        <war destfile="${build.dir}/webserviceTest.war" webxml="${dist.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml" manifest="${dist.dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
            <fileset dir="${dist.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
                <exclude name="**/web.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>

        <echo message=" **** webserviceTest War file created and available in build folder... "/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean"
            description="clean up" >
        <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
        <echo message=" ***** Deleting existing build directory ***** "/>
        <delete file="${dist.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/webserviceTest.jar"/>
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <echo message=" ***** Existing build directory deleted ***** "/>
    </target>


</project>
```

Please have a look at web.xml and other two xml configurations below

WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>webserviceTest</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>HelloService</display-name>
        <servlet-name>HelloService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

SUN-WEB.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/helloservice</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
</sun-web-app>
```

SUN-JAXWS.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<endpoints xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime' version='2.0'>
    <endpoint
        name='HelloService'
        implementation='com.arun.HelloClass'
        url-pattern='/hello'/>
</endpoints>
```

I place all the three xmls in the WAR file and then deploy it in server. I get exception message and my war is not getting extracted in JBOSS

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:262)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3859)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
17:53:38,571 ERROR [[/webserviceTest]] Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
17:53:38,576 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
17:53:38,582 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/webserviceTest] startup failed due to previous errors
17:53:38,589 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/webserviceTest state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a2a1u4d-cpdzfu-gyr6vrx0-1-gyr6wrj8-9q/webserviceTest.war/ deployment failed
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:331)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
17:53:38,917 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfszip:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/webserviceTest.war/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a2a1u4d-cpdzfu-gyr6vrx0-1-gyr6wrj8-9q/webserviceTest.war/ deployment failed
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:331)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
17:53:39,236 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfszip:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/webserviceTest.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/softwares/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a2a1u4d-cpdzfu-gyr6vrx0-1-gyr6wrj8-9q/webserviceTest.war/ deployment failed

17:53:39,279 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
17:53:39,299 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
17:53:39,309 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 47s:687ms
```

Please help me on this.

As am new to this area, i guess am doing something very silly and thats why i get this error.

Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your servlet-class is incorrect in your web.xml